Django не сохраняется форма
Есть страница в выводом данных о заявке на обслуживание. На этой странице есть форма для комментария исполнителя. Мне необходимо, чтобы когда пользователь заполнял поле комментария и нажимал кнопку "задача выполнена", значение данного поля сохранялось в базу, а статус заявки менялся. Для этого я написал отдельную вьюшку, так как менять значение полей в Django через стандартное submit нельзя.
Но почему-то форма не сохраняется и статус заявки не изменяется. При этом, если на форме использовать обычную кнопку submit, то все нормально, записи заносятся в базу, но статус заявки, при этом, не меняется. Как можно это исправить?
forms.py
class Request_response(forms.ModelForm):
    commentary = forms.CharField(label='Описание работ...', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Requests
        fields = ('commentary')

views.py
def review(request, pk):
    request1 = Requests.objects.get(pk=pk)
    response_form = Request_response(instance=request1)
    status = Statuses.objects.get(id='3')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_form = Request_response(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request1)
        if response_form.is_valid():
            request1.status_id = status
            request1.save()
            return redirect('requests')
        else:
            response_form = Request_response()
        return render(request, 'main/request_view.html', {'request1': request1, 'response_form': response_form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/request_view.html', {'request1': request1, 'response_form': response_form})


request_view.html
{% block main %}
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h3>Заявка №{{request1.id}} от {{request1.request_date}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="rows">
                        <p class="detailed_view_headers">Название заявки:</p>
                        <div class="detailed_view_fields">{{request1.request_name|default_if_none:'' }}</div>
                            <p class="detailed_view_headers">Статус: {{ request1.status }}</p>

                            ...

                        {% if status == 2 %}
                            {% if is_moderator %}
                                <p>Комментарий исполнителя:</p>
                                {{ response_form.commentary }}
                                <p>Прикрепить объекты: {{ response_form.responce_attachments }}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}

                        ...

                      {% elif status == 2 %}
                        {% if is_moderator %}
                            <button type="submit" class="submit_button">Задача выполнена 1</button>
                            <a href="{% url 'request_review' request1.id %}" class="submit_button">Задача выполнена</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'request_cancellation' request1.id %}" class="cancel_button">Отменить заявку</a>
                        {% endif %}

                        ...


urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('requests/<int:pk>',views.request_view, name='request_details'),
    path('requests/<int:pk>/review', views.review, name='request_review'),


"менять значение полей в Django через стандартное submit нельзя" - что?

Зачем у вас есть одновременно кнопка "Задача выполнена 1" и ссылка "Задача выполнена"?
